# How can I solve the following 2nd Order DE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$y''-\frac{1}{x}y'=2x\cdot cos(x)$$

For the homogeneous part I multiplied through with $x^2$ and got a second order Cauchy Euler equation with the general solution: $$y_h (x)=A x^2 +B$$

Then for the particular solution I tried using the method of undetermined coefficients but the whole thing became too entangled to solve and I couldn't get anywhere!

Maple tells me the solution is: $$2sin(x) - 2x\cdot cos(x)+ \frac{C_1\cdot x^2 }{2}+C_2$$
but I can't figure it out...
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What happens if you set $y' = v(x)$, substitute and see if you get an easier ODE to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reduces the problem to a first order Diff Eq.
$u= y'\\
xu' - u = 2x^2\cos x$

Choose a candidate for the particular solution that could work.

$u_p = x\sin x$
"Generalize" this by adding terms that might come up in the derivative that we hope will cancel out.  Give every term a coefficient.

$u_p = Ax\sin x + Bx\cos x + C\sin x+ D\cos x$

Differentiate and plug into the original equation.

$u_p' = A\sin x + Ax\cos x + B\cos x - Bx\sin x + C\cos x - D\sin x\\
u_p' = - Bx\sin x + Ax\cos x + (A-D)\sin x + (B+C)\cos x$

$xu_p' - u_p = - Bx^2\sin x +  Ax^2\cos x -Dx\sin x + Cx\cos x - C\sin x - D\cos x = 2x^2\cos x$

$A = 2, B,C,D = 0$

$u_p = 2x\sin x\\
y_p' = 2x\sin x\\
y_p = \int x\sin x \ dx = -2x\cos x + 2\sin x + C$

$y = y_h + y_p = Ax^2 + B - 2x\cos x + 2\sin x$

Answer (score 2):

$$y''-\frac{1}{x}y'=2x\cos(x)$$
$$\dfrac {xy''-y'}{x^2}=2\cos(x)$$
$$\left (\dfrac {y'}{x} \right)'=2\cos(x)$$
Integrate.